# Python: How to model 3D objects and interact them in 3D space?

Tags: python, 3d

Could anyone suggest a python library which has the ability to construct simple 3D objects and interact(touch) them?

Here's what I'm exactly looking into:

1. To have a test object, square/rectangular box(or any object) on a ground plane.
2. To have another sphere object of certain diameter.
3. To simulate, i.e. the roll the sphere all over and all sides of the test object.
4. To highlight or shade the parts of the test objects that are touched during the rolling process. (it won't roll all over, due to the ground plane restriction)
5. Not interested to see any animations, just the end product of the test object which were touched by the sphere.

Any suggestions on libraries or mathematical methods?

Many thanks.

p.s. In electrical engineering, this is one of the method to see which part of the building the lightning may be able to strike, i.e the "touched" area.

Comment: The easiest way for you to do that is to use Blender. It has built-in physics engine, modeling and python scripting. While it is possible to do what you want in pure python, it'll be probably way too difficult for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) for this.

Blender is a full-blown 3D modeler (so you can quickly create arbitrary scenes from simple building blocks like spheres), it has a raytracer (so you can see how shadows are cast without writing a single line of code) and, best of all, it can be easily [scripted with Python](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/).

Answer (score 1):

Vtk is a very sophisticated framework, but it might be overkill.